# Why does str.join inside a parse action produce an exception?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm getting very strange behavior with PyParsing when I try to use `" ".join(...)` inside a nested function that is used as a parse action. For example, this:

```
from pyparsing import *

def sigh(p):
        def nested_func(t):
           " ".join(t)
        parser = Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphas))).setParseAction(nested_func)
        return parser.parseString(p)
def works(p):
        def nested_func(t):
           print("no join!")
        parser = Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphas))).setParseAction(nested_func)
        return parser.parseString(p)
def functions(p):
        def nested_func(t):
           " ".join(t)
        parser = OneOrMore(Word(alphas)).setParseAction(nested_func)
        return parser.parseString(p)
def notnested(t):
  " ".join(t)
def alsoworks(p):
        parser = OneOrMore(Word(alphas)).setParseAction(notnested)
        return parser.parseString(p)
s = "boom baba boom"
print(sigh(s)) # comment me out
print(works(s)) 
print(functions(s))
print(alsoworks(s))
```

produces an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(sigh(s)) # comment me out
  File "test.py", line 7, in sigh
    return name.parseString(p)
  File "C:\...\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1031, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "C:\...\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 931, in _parseNoCache
    tokens = fn( instring, tokensStart, retTokens )
  File "C:\...\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 695, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args[limit[0]:])
TypeError: nested_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'
```

but if I comment out `print(sigh(s))` everything works fine. I'm stumped. Why does the *contents* of `nested_func` changes how PyParsing *calls* it?

I'm using WinPython which came with Python 3.3.3 and PyParsing 2.0.1.

Comment: Why do you name your functions `lambda_func`? It's not very descriptive, especially since none of those functions are lambdas.

Comment: One thing that is different in `functions()` and `alsoworks()` is you are not wrapping `OneOrMoreWord()` with `Group()`. Do you get the same error in those two functions if you wrap `OneOrMoreWord()` with `Group()`?

Comment: When I look at the output of `Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphas)))` it comes out `([(['boom', 'baba', 'boom'], {})], {})`.  When I pass that structure to `" ".join()` I get an exception because the first sequence item is a list.  Is that data structure what you really want?

Comment: @user2357112, because it's an example. I tried to keep the names generic but a step up from `a(..)`, `b(...)`, etc. It's also named wrong since it's a nested function not a lambda.

Comment: @MauriceReeves, thanks! That solved my actual problem. I still don't understand why it generates the exception it does.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the version that fails defines the parser as `Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphas)))` while the version that succeeds defines the parser as just `OneOrMore(Word(alphas))`. Group encloses your list of words within another list. It is like saying, "this works: ' '.join(['a','b','c']), but this fails: ' '.join([['a','b','c']])".  You aren't changing how the parse action is being called, you are changing the structure of the tokens being passed to it, enclosing them within another level of list.

(Actually pyparsing returns ParseResults, not just lists. ParseResults can be indexed through like a list, but they can also have named results, like a dict or a namedtuple. That is why printing out the tokens looks like a list + a dict, but that is just the string representation of a ParseResults. It is not really a tuple of a list and a dict.)

Comment: Thank you. I understand now that `Group` was unnecessary and was causing `join` to fail. What I don't understand is why it's failing with an exception about `nested_func` missing a required positional argument. I guess I'll never know.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, which is really a hell :(, the action function should have 3 parameters, just like this:

```
def nested_func(origString, loc, tokens):
    your code;
```

This only happens to the first function "sigh(p)", others are OK, maybe it has something with Group